# Are Javascript date/time functions dependent on the client machine?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I was wondering if Javascript date/time functions will always return [correct, universal dates/times](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&rlz=1C1GGLS_enUS291US305&q=current+time&aq=f&oq=&aqi=g10) 
or whether, Javascript being a client-side language, they are dependent on what the client machine has its date set to.

If it is dependent on the client machine, what is the best way to get the correct universal time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As thomasrutter has said javascript date functions are reliant on the client's machine. However if you want to get an authoritative date you could make and ajax request to your server that just returns the date string. You can then convert the date string into a date object with the following

```
var ds = ... // Some ajax call
var d = new Date(ds);
```

Answer (score 13):

Javascript only knows as much about the correct time as the environment it is currently running within, and Javascript is **[client-side](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client-side_scripting)**.

So, Javascript is at the mercy of the user having the correct time, AND timezone, settings on the PC on which they are browsing.

If the user has the incorrect time zone, but correct time, then functions depending on time zones like getUTCDate() will be incorrect.

If the user has the incorrect time, then all time-related functions in Javascript will be incorrect.

One could make the argument, however, that if the user wanted correct times on their PC they would have set the correct time.  The counter to that is that the user may not know how to do that.

Edit Jun 2020: It is common now for operating systems to update the computer's system time automatically from a time server, significantly reducing the chances of incorrect time on the client.  There is still a possibility of an incorrect time *zone*, but this too is often geo-detected somehow by systems during installation and/or is tied to the user's supplied country of residence in their relevant online account.

Answer (score 5):

> or whether, Javascript being a client-side language, they are dependent on what the client machine has its date set to.

Yes, this is correct.

> If it is dependent on the client machine, what is the best way to get the correct universal time?

To get the time/date from an authoritative source, not from a client machine.

Comment: Client time data is not trustworthy for critical applications.  But I think the OP already knows that.

Comment: Is there an authoritative source that exposes an API?

Comment: It'd be best to do it yourself by having your server sync up using ntp.

Comment: The authoritative source that exposes an API is the ntp.org servers, and the API is the NTP protocol.  It's a well known protocol so there should be support for your programming language of choice, but if you want to roll your own using sockets it's a very simple protocol.  As the above comment suggests an easy way would be simply to ensure your own server is using NTP to sync (many do anyway), and have the client just given the time from your server.

Answer (score 2):

The methods do what they're documented to do.  The best way to get UTC info is obviously to use the UTC methods:

[getUTCFullYear()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getUTCFullYear.asp), [getUTCMonth()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getUTCMonth.asp), [getUTCDate()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getUTCDate.asp), etc.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript's date() constructor will always get the time of local machine.

The best way to get the universal time are

1) get the time from your server by an ajax call. This method will always show your server time no matter where your user is.

2) Get the time from an third party server. Use a third party server to get time from any time zone / country of the world. Here I'm explaining this method by using plain javascript and axios. The service I'm using is [worldtimeapi.org/](http://worldtimeapi.org/)

**VANILLA JS**

```
function getTime(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open("GET", url);
        req.onload = () =>
            req.status === 200
                ? resolve(req.response)
                : reject(Error(req.statusText));
        req.onerror = (e) => reject(Error(`Network Error: ${e}`));
        req.send();
    });
}
```

Now Use this function to make the ajax call

```
let url = "http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Etc/GMT";

getTime(url)
    .then((response) => {
        let dateObj = JSON.parse(response);
        let dateTime = dateObj.datetime;
        console.log(dateObj);
        console.log(dateTime);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

**AXIOS**

```
axios({
    url:"http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Etc/GMT",
    method: "get",
})
    .then((response) => {
        let dateObj = response.data;
        let dateTime = dateObj.datetime;
        console.log(dateObj);
        console.log(dateTime);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

Hope that helps. Bear one thing in mind though, [worldtimeapi.org/](http://worldtimeapi.org/) is a third party service. If they choose to terminate their service, your code will break. Happy coding.