# How javascript determines what current date is?

Tags: javascript, time

Consider this line of code:

```
var currentTime = new Date();
```

Did it look at my IP address? Did it talk to my local machine?
How javascript determines what current time in my time zone is?

Comment: The JavaScript engine, inside the browser, asks the operating system.

Comment: The only source of information Javascript has is the operating system where it's running. Set your PC to any time in any zone you like: Javascript won't know the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since javascript is a client-side language, the Date() method implemented in the browser is querying the client machine for the current time.  If you want a date you can trust, query a server for a timestamp and use that in your calculations.

[Relevant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1016341/293492)

Answer (score 1):

The JavaScript parser asks the browser, which asks the computer, which looks it up internally. Most languages have a feature for date/time.

Answer (score 0):

It uses the timezone that's configured in the OS the browser is running on.

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript `Date()` function returns number of milliseconds from 1 January, 1970 UTC.
If no arguments are provided to the constructor (`new Date()`), the constructor creates a Date object for the current time according to your system settings