# Why are Date.now() and System.currentTimeMillis() returning different values?

Tags: javascript, java, android, date, time

I have an android app and a web app which are connected together. On clicking a button in the web app, a notification is instantly sent to the android app. The moment the button on the web app is clicked, I need to record the current time in both apps.

On the web app I'm using Date.now() to record the time. And in the android app I'm using System.currentTimeMillis() to record the time. When the button is clicked in the web app, it only takes a couple seconds for the notification to reach the android app. Hence, the time recorded in both places must differ by only a few seconds.

But the following timestamps are getting recorded in both places:

```
Web app- using Date.now() - 1653945533308

Android app- using System.currentTimeMillis() - 1653945810727
```

These timestamps have a difference of 5 minutes, which is wrong. It looks like for some reason, the timestamps getting logged by the 2 apis are not exactly the same at the same time.

Why is this happening? Is there a way to ensure that "Date.now() in javascript" and "System.currentTimeMillis() in java" both record the same timestamp at the same time?

Comment: Is the system clock accurate on both ends?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Yes it is

Comment: how do you know that they are recording on same time? If you execute first one, it will be having slight diff from the second one.

Comment: @Pirate Thats obviouse, but he also mention that his differenz is 5 min

Answer (score 1):

As @RobbyCornelissen is onto, this is probably related to systems clocks. JavaScript Date can only be as accurate as the clock of the system it's running on.
See [this relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016043/are-javascript-date-time-functions-dependent-on-the-client-machine) for a brief discussion on the topic. The same goes for Java, and there is also a discussion [in the Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) about discrepancies between system time and UTC time. I'm assuming you're running your android-app on some sort of emulator of physical device, so that might be were the system time differs.

Programatically, you could, depending on the use case, always solve this by passing the clock/date from the web-app to the API, or the other way around. Clocks have always been an issue on computer design, and there is a bunch of research on it, so you should have no difficulties stumbling upon some similar issue in the litterature.

Comment: Ok so if "Date.now() in javascript" and "System.currentTimeMillis() in java" are executed on the same android device, would they record the same time? I assume they would because it's the same device, right? Basically, on the android device I want to get time1 from System.currentTimeMillis() in the java android code; and time2 from date.now() in some javascript in a webview. And then do time2-time1. Would these 2 times have the same baseline? I mean would it be accurate to subtract them?

Comment: Yes, if they are running on the same device, the times would be correct in some granularity. They won't be correct down to the nanosecond (or even microsecond), as they run on different (virtual) machines even if running on the same hardware. However, you should not get a difference as large as 5 minutes.

Comment: I know this might be a bit out of what you're asking, but keep in mind what happens if the client and server is in different timezones, or the client has set the clock back an hour. I believe there are better ways of measuring request-times. One of the simplest is sending a request, waiting for a reponse, and measure the time between the request and response. One slight fun fact: this is how the speed of light is measured. You cannot measure the speed of light in just one direction, due to the difficulty with clocks. Sounds familiar?